# Cluster permissions for RabbitMQ Operator

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-cluster

I have a Kubernetes cluster that contains a rabbitMQ Cluster Operator. It is in the namespace rabbitmq-system. Also here I have a clusterRole named rabbitmq-cluster-operator. This ClusterRole has access to secrets with the verbs "create, get, list, update, watch".

Does the ClusterRole need this much access to secrets? Can these verbs be deleted?